# jQuery is executing in the Chrome Extension content script but it returns undefined for the content of every element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm making a very simple chrome extension and I want to interact with the DOM using jQuery in my content script. By placing jquery.js first in the script order in the manifest it change from an error about $ being undefined to returning undefined for all elements.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Desc",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Title"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "all_frames": true,
        "js":      ["scripts/jquery.min.js", "scripts/content.js"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/; object-src 'self'"
}
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{   
    if (data == 'button1')
    {
        // Do button 1 stuff
        console.log(jQuery("head").html());
    }

    sendResponse({data: data, success: true});
});
```

Everything works regarding the popup so I haven't included that for brevity and getting it to execute the content script is fine, but the log always has 'undefined' no matter what I use for my selector, header is just an obvious one that should be there for most pages but isn't. I tried both $ and jQuery. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your content script runs in all frames so every instance wants to display an alert but only one can do it. Don't use `alert`, there are much better methods of displaying info and debugging code. Use `console.log` or utilize devtools' built-in debugger: set a breakpoint in the code and inspect what happens in DOM at the time the message arrives.

Comment: Sorry, the actual script uses console.log and it displays undefined for any selector I use in the content script, the same selectors work fine in console on the page.

Comment: The posted fragment of code is correct and it should work so I can only guess what happens there. The most common pitfalls are: doing something differently in the real code,not reloading both the extension and the tab after changing the content script or manifest.json, not sending the message correctly. All of these should be trivial to spot if you use devtools debugger.

Comment: I know, I've been very careful to reload and refresh, that's why I've resorted to stack overflow, out of frustration at things-it-could-possibly-be, I removed the content_security_policy line from the manifest and it fixed it. Go figure.

Comment: Since content_security_policy doesn't affect content scripts the problem was caused by something else.

Comment: I literally didn't change anything else, not even a space or a tab, I only removed that one line and refreshed/reloaded and it's selecting things now...

Comment: Then the only other explanation is that this was a bug in Chrome. However I'm more inclined to think you somehow didn't reload the extension properly.

Comment: For what it's worth I've been developing for 20 years, I'm not some script kiddie that doesn't know what he's doing, I 100% reloaded and refreshed the page, even using Ctrl F5 to do a full refresh in case by some stupid coincidence it wasn't reloading the content script because of the cache, multiple times to be sure, I removed that line refreshed and removed and it worked.

Comment: Yeah then it's a bug. If you can reproduce it consistently consider reporting on https://crbug.com.

Comment: I stand correct @wOxxOm - it was actually frames, and because it randomly switches between which frame gets called first I was seeing erroneous results. It was coincidence removing the policy from the manifest just switched which came first and I thought I fixed it, when it stopped working again I did some more looking and realised it's being called twice on the page because of the iframe. Do you know of a better way to only run on the main page other than checking window.self != window.top?

Comment: Checking self/top is fine, everyone does that, nothing shameful :-) but if you never need anything from frames then remove "all_frames": true from manifest.json.